# Auto populate primary contact from related tab items in Opportunity to another object field

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, automated-process

I have created a process builder to auto populate fields from opportunity to another object as soon the opportunity is a win. So a record is created as soon its a win and fills out required fields from opportunity. The challenge here is one of the field required to pull is there in a related items tab of opportunity object and i am not able to create a field reference in process builder as its not available on opportunity object to auto fill the field in another object. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add more details about what data you are trying to pull from the  related records.  You will probably have to build a Flow to do what you want.